# How to save and restore state of automatically added nested fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

> Quick note: I did my due diligence before asking the question: I know that this sounds like a dupe. But none of the existing questions ask the exact question I have, and none of the solutions on the existing questions work for me. Thanks.

---

TL;DR: When restoring a fragment that has a nested fragment, the `childFragmentManager` adds the nested fragment back, but does not restore its state. How do I make it do so?

---

I have a `ViewPager` that is backed by a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. The `FSPA` returns fragments, each of which in turn have one other fragment added when `setUserVisibleHint` is `true`. I'm basically avoiding the cost of loading one offscreen fragment which is the default `ViewPager` behaviour. The inner fragment is a list of items, so maintaining scroll position is important.

Here's the sequence of events:

- Open page `N`, because it's visible, the inner fragment is added
- Go to page `N+2` or `N-2`: now the fragment at position `N` is destroyed because it's past the `ViewPager`'s `offScreenLimit` of 1
- Then when I come back to `N`, the fragment manager conveniently added the inner fragment back (because of `savedInstanceState` I'm guessing)
- BUT: and here's the bug: the newly added child fragment's state is not saved or restored: the fragment is freshly created

This leads to a terrible user experience because when coming back to position `N`, the list is scrolled all the way back to top.

Is there any way to avoid this? I have tried:

- manually saving the state using `getChildFragmentManager().saveFragmentInstanceState(myInnerFragment)`

  - but I don't know where or how to restore it because the child fragment manager added the fragment back for me
- retaining the instance variable `mInnerFragment` and replacing the automatically added fragment with this

  - this is wrong for a lot of reasons, but it also looks bad because we're replacing the already added fragment with this one so there is a visible jumping when swiping back to position `N`

Note that I can't use `setRetainInstanceState(true)` in any of the fragments: outer or inner, because all this is nested in another fragment. A lot of the answers have suggested using reflection to hang on to and restore the `mChildFragmentManager`, but that seems risky, and in any case I can't use that because of the `setRetainInstance` restriction.

---

### Code

#### OuterFragment.java

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    if (!isVisibleToUser) {
        return;
    }

    addInnerFragment();
}

private void addInnerFragment() {
    if (getInnerFragment() != null && getInnerFragment().isAdded()) {
        return;
    }

    FragmentTransaction transaction =
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(
        R.id.fragment_container,
        getInnerFragment(),
        FRAGMENT_TAG);
    transaction.commit();
}

private Fragment getInnerFragment() {
    if (mInnerFragment != null) {
        return mInnerFragment;
    }

    // The fragment could have already been added if we're coming back from a savedInstanceState.
    Fragment fragment =
        getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (fragment != null) {
        // Verified using debugger that this condition is being hit when I come
        // back to `N`
        mInnerFragment = fragment;
        return mInnerFragment;
    }

    mInnerFragment = InnerFragment.newInstance();
    return mInnerFragment;
}
```

Comment: In its simplest form, what I could do is save the state of the inner fragment myself in outer fragment's `onSaveInstanceState`, and restore it before the fragment manager automatically adds the fragment back. While it's easy to do the first part, there is no callback available or a mechanism to hook into fragmentmanager to provide my own state.